# nesting using Zend\Db\Sql\Where

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2

I am using zend frame work 2. While trying this code:

```
 $where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where(); 
 $where->nest();

        foreach ($Array as $value)
        {
            $count++;
            if ($value == 'dump')
            {
                $where = $this->function ( $where );

            }

            if ($count < count ( $Array ))
            {
                $where->and;
            }
        }
  $where->unnest();
```

Im getting an error message by the unnest() saying "Not nested". what could be wrong?!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You may NOT remove code that you think is unneccessary. Right now what you show us is just not doing anything, so show us your real deal ;) That dump stuff looks weird so far...

Comment: With a little assumption of your code, your want the statements to the added to `$where` on those `if` conditions. `nest()` and `unnest()` does not work if there is not enough nesting data available for it.